# linear algebra 1 - Finding x

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help question I'm not sure if I solved the question properly.

the question:

[image: image here]

My answer:

[image]
[image]

thank's.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is wrong. Note that

$$B^2X(2B)^{-1}=B+I\iff X(2B)^{-1}=(B^2)^{-1}(B+I)\iff X=(B^2)^{-1}(B+I)(2B).$$

(Where is your mistake? You have multiplied by the right in the RHS by $(B^2)^{-1}$ but you have to multiply by the left. There is missing a parenthesis also. It must be $(B+I)$.)

We can simplify it to get

$$X=2(B^2)^{-1}(B^2+B)=2(I+B^{-1}).$$ Thus

$$X=\begin{pmatrix}20& -4\\ -8 & 4\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$B^2X(2B)^{-1} = B+I$

$\frac{B^2X(B)^{-1}}{2} = B+I$

$B.B.X.(B)^{-1} = 2(B+I)$

**$[B.B^{-1} = 1]$**

$B.X.I = 2B + 2I$

$B.X = 2B + 2I$

**[ B.I = B]**

$X = 2 + 2.I.B^{-1}$

**$[I.B^{-1} = B^{-1}]$**

$X = 2.I+ 2.B^{-1}$

Now solve it.